# getting an index from array and output it in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, user-input, bufferedreader

I want to be able to choose an array index using input.

```
Object stud1 [][] = {
          {1,2,3},
          {"favorite food: ","pet name: ","bday: "}
          }

System.out.println("how many inputs?");
```

If a user inputs 1, then "favorite food:" will prompt the user and if the user inputs 2, then 
both "favorite food: " and "pet name: " will prompt the user and so on.

After the user completes the prompt input, this will display:

```
  favorite food: chicken
  pet: doge
  birthday: december 25,1994
```

/////////////////////////////////////////my code/////////////////////////////////////////////

This question is similar to my other question, I just could not find the right answer for my question because I think it was confusing and not specific enough.

It's kind of working already but the problem is that when I input 1 then it still outputs everything. I only want it to output everything if the user inputs 3 which is the number of indexes in my array.

I am not pretty good with arrays yet especially multi array, I'm still experimenting.

```
 String ctr1;

 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


 System.out.print("Enter How Many Inputs: ");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    if (num1 <= stud1.length) {
        for (int x = 1; x<stud1.length;x++){
            for (int i = 0; i<stud1[x].length;){
                /*System.out.print("Enter Value #" + x++ +":");
                 ctr1 =Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                i++;*/

                System.out.println(stud1[x][i]);
                ctr1 =in.readLine();
                i++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is stud1? You never declared stud1 and you never modify stud1 in your double for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but I don't think this is a good example for multidimensional arrays... nothing is really being done with the first element here: `{1,2,3}`.

To answer the specific question of why all 3 elements are printing out when the user only inputs a "1", it is because that value is being read into the variable `num1`, but `num1` is not used anywhere in the loop that prints the output. If you want the input to control how many values are printed, then `num1` needs to be used in the `for` loop's test expression (the middle phrase in the parentheses). I think a good first step is to change your inner loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i<num1;i++){
     System.out.println(stud1[1][i]);
     ctr1 =in.readLine();
}
```

Also note that the `i++` is moved inside the parentheses for the `for` loop. That's really where it belongs, if you're using `for`.

Hope this helps!